# Insect identification request - Is this a bed bug? Colorado, USA

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I found three of these bugs in our friends house all dead. I never found an alive one… But I’ve been waking up with bites in the breakfast lunch and dinner pattern.

I want to confirm they are bedbugs before I tell them about it in fear of embarrassing them

[image]